# How to retrieve the list of users who subscribed to a report

Tags: soql, reporting, subscriber, entitysubscription

I tried a soql which should return the list of user ids who subscribed to a particular report. Below is my soql, but it returns no results.

```
select id, subscriberid from entitysubscription where parentid = '00O************'
```

From the document of EntitySubscription object, I noticed that ParentId refers to Report also. Can anyone suggest me how to retrieve this info or is this the limitation on SF end.

Comment: The entitysubscription Object refers to users Following a Record or another User, but not a Report Subscription. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try a REST call as mentioned in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_notifications_reference_notification.htm)

```
/services/data/v50.0/analytics/notifications?source=lightningReportSubscribe
```

Here are some of the subscriptions you can check:

- lightningSubscribe — report subscriptions
- lightningDashboardSubscribe — dashboard subscriptions
- lightningReportSubscribe — report subscriptions
- waveNotification — Tableau CRM notifications

A sample response that contains recipients which should give the user Id's

> "source":"lightningReportSubscribe","thresholds":[{"actions":[{"configuration":{"recipients":[]},"type":"sendEmail"}],"conditions":null,"type":"always"}]}

Screenshot from my dev org
[image]

Comment: I also came across [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FAgN6UAL&_ga=2.26578173.1748452205.1636612597-1084922768.1636612078) paid app exchange package that might help. I've not tried it from my end.

Comment: I've tried what you answered above using RESE API. /services/data/v52.0/analytics/notifications?source=lightningReportSubscribe&ownerId='005************'. But it shows nothing in the result

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct and should return the list of user IDs that subscribed to the report with the specified ParentId.

However, it is possible that the report with that ParentId does not have any subscribers. To verify if this is the case, you can try checking the number of subscribers for that report in the Salesforce user interface. If there are subscribers, make sure that you have the necessary permissions to view the EntitySubscription object.